# Call to a member function can() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.7, I'm following the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#via-blade-templates

```
@if(auth()->user()->can('update-properties') and $child_types)
     {!! Form::select('type_2', $type_2_options, null, ['placeholder' => __('places.none'), 'class' => 'custom-select custom-select-sm w-50']) !!}
@else
```

And I get the error

> Call to a member function can() on null

I thought the `can()` method was always available? Surely I don't have to check for auth()->user() being null before every single time I test for a gate?

Comment: Of course if you're calling can on `auth()->user()`, you have to verify there is a user returned.   Why would `can` always be available?

Comment: Because the docs say it is

Comment: Of course the method `can()` is always available on the `Auth::user()` object. Doesn't mean that object is always available. If you want a view that can be seen by unauthorized users, use `@auth`/`@else`/`@endauth` to show certain parts.

Comment: Where do the docs say that `auth()->user()->can()` is always available?  The API docs state that user() can return null or an Authenticatable instance: https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html#method_user

Comment: So I need to wrap it in `optional(auth()->user())->can('update-properties')` every time I need to test a gate?

Comment: Or you could just use @auth and @can blade directives like the docs you linked to show.  But yes, if you are calling a method on an object, you need to make sure that object exists.  It seems like you're new to PHP and OOP based on this question, so I wouldn't get in the habit of using Laravel's `optional()` helper everywhere.   This type of logic isn't just Laravel or PHP.  In any programming language, calling a method on null is going to result in an error.

Comment: No it's just that `@can` works, and then the docs say`statements above respectively translate to the following statements:@if (Auth::user()->can('update', $post))`, so I took translate to mean translate, but what it actually means is it does an extra check that isn't included, and not translate

Comment: @Lee is the endpoint(route) that returns this response(view) behind the auth middleware? Can you post some code for your route definition?

Comment: @Lee You are right. Gates return automatically false if $user is null. People expected the policies will behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is returning null, in this case it is most likely because the user is un-authenticated/logged out.
Try

```
  @if(!Auth::guest()) 

    @if(auth()->user()->can('update-properties') and $child_types)
     {!! Form::select('type_2', $type_2_options, null, ['placeholder' => __('places.none'), 'class' => 'custom-select custom-select-sm w-50']) !!}
    @else

     (rest of code here)

  @endif
```

Comment: `@auth` is better

Answer (score 1):

[Use the Blade helpers for authorization checks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#via-blade-templates), not calling them directly on the user model. It breaks in your example because there is no authenticated user so you're calling `can` on null.

```
// Map directly to a model policy
@can('update', $property)
    //
@endcan

// Use custom action
@can('update-properties)
    //
@endcan
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error is Auth::user() function can't able to find the logged user...and If you are logged and again you are getting error means make sure the session expired or not. Because Sometime we forgot the session expiry while sincerely working. 
To avoid this protect your routes with auth middleware also use this in your controller too. So if the session is expired and you are hitting the view page it will automatically take you to login screen.

Answer (score 0):

auth()->user() is only available when you’re logged in so this view will either need to be behind the auth middleware or you can use the auth blade directive to get it to work:

```
@auth // use helper function


@auth
    @if (auth()->user()->can('update-properties') and $child_types)
        {!! Form::select('type_2', $type_2_options, null, ['placeholder' => __('places.none'), 'class' => 'custom-select custom-select-sm w-50']) !!}
    @endif
@endauth
```